# How to solve this error Error: Could not resolve the package

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

```
Compiler message:
Error: Could not resolve the package 'razorpay_flutter' in 
'package:razorpay_flutter/razorpay_flutter.dart'.
lib/Screens/add_amount.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 
'package:razorpay_flutter/razorpay_flutter.dart'
import 'package:razorpay_flutter/razorpay_flutter.dart';
```

I a implementing the flutter_razorpay in my flutter application but i am getting this error. And then i created a new project and again implemented this but same error appear every time when i import the package and hot reload

```
name: gamershub
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  flutter_spinkit: ^4.1.2+1
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.6
  google_sign_in: ^4.5.1
  flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0
  firebase_auth: ^0.16.0
  fluttertoast: ^4.0.1
  razorpay_flutter:
dev_dependencies:
   flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Comment: Can you add your pubspec.yaml file and also run 'flutter doctor' and edit your answer to include both of those things

Answer (score 1):

i think you have not mentioned the version code :)

```
dependencies:
   razorpay_flutter: ^1.2.1
```

make sure the pubspec.yaml file has this, and make sure you follow the required indentations

if you still have not got it fixed...

1. Run `flutter doctor` in the command-line make sure there aren't any errors
2. make sure you do a `flutter packages get` if flutter did not automatically do that for you
3. then run `flutter pub cache repair` which should fix the error for you

Answer (score 0):

There is a big chance either you are trying to use an incorrect version of the package or your indentation in pubspec.yaml might be wrong.

If that will not work for you. Please share your pubspec.yaml

Comment: I have uploaded all the dependencies are working instead of this